# How do I get GCC on OS X Lion?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, makefile, osx-lion

I recently bought a new Mac and did a time machine restore of my old mac & updated the xCode version to the latest version. After the move I have lost the ability to use Make and GCC; saying these commands are unavailable. I use Make and GCC to develop for homework assignments for classes that I later SCP up to a Linux box at school then run from there.

How do I get GCC and Make for Mac OS Lion? I've seen some articles on how to install via source via compiling but they automatically assume you have GCC installed, which I do not.

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gcc should be in `/Developer/usr/bin/`. Check there.

Comment: Doing a LS, shows me it's located there, but how do I get the terminal to recognize the command GCC without navigation to /Developer/usr/bin

Comment: You should be able to add it to PATH: `export PATH=/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to download Xcode from the app store
2. You have to run the Install Xcode application
3. Within Xcode go to *Preferences* -> *Downloads* and click *install* for the command line tools

You'll find the tools at the usual place, for example /usr/bin/make.

See also [post on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/313107/does-updating-to-os-x-lion-delete-gcc)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the App Store and download XCode. It's free. It will give you llvm (compiler), make and related tools.

Comment: I DO NOT WANT LLVM. I NEED GCC.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately justing updating the path (which I found not in any /Developer but actually in /Applications/Xcode.app) doesn't solve other issues like missing manpages.  Apple has released a new developer download for command line developer tools.  Either go directly to Apple's developer page, for find a little more info and the link [here](http://staticimport.blogspot.com/2012/02/mac-os-x-lion-command-line-developer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Install homebrew from [here](https://homebrew.org)
then in zsh type
`brew install gcc`
then,
`gcc --version`
and you're good to go.